# How do I retrieve an XDocument's Element Value in XML escaped format?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I am building an XDocument and I have unit tests to test the output. One of the things I want to test for is that invalid strings are being formatted for XML properly. I have discovered that calling .ToString() on the XDoc itself properly formats the invalid strings for XML. However, in my testing I am retrieving specific Elements or Attributes off of the XDoc and testing the values. This does not format the values for XML. How do I go about getting these values in their escaped format?

Answer: (thx Ed Plunkett)

```
myXDoc.Descendants("element2").First().FirstNode.ToString();
// result "Pork&amp;Beans"
```

Sample:

```
var xml = 
"<element1>" +
    "<element2>Pork&Beans</element2>" +
"</element1>";

var myXDoc = XDocument.Load(xml);

var xDocString = myXDoc.ToString();
// result is formatted - <element1> <element2>Pork&amp;Beans</element2> </element1>

var element2Value = myXDoc.Decendents("element2").First().Value;
// result is unformatted - Pork&Beans
```

Comment: So to be clear, you want the entire XML string in an unformatted format?

Comment: `myXDoc.Descendants("element2").First().ToString()`. By the way your example code needs a bit of work before it compiles.

Comment: Calling ToString() on the element results in "<element2>Pork&amp;Beans</element2>" which is not ideal. I am hoping to get "Pork&amp;Beans".

Comment: @Sach No, I am looking to get just that one value that I query for in its XML safe format.

Comment: Any objection to using `System.Xml.XmlDocument` instead of `XDocument`? `XmlNode.InnerXml` will give you what you want.

Comment: If you want the inner text of an element, use `element.Value`

Comment: Your `xml` is not valid XML, you wouldn't be able to parse it in the first place...

Comment: Also, if you are using `XDocument` and friends, you don't need to worry about the data being formatted correctly, it will do it for you. If you're building your XML by hand... you shouldn't be in the first place...

Comment: You're essentially testing that LINQ to XML works properly. I'm not sure this test adds much value given Microsoft will have done this already.

Comment: @ Chuck Savage Using element.Value gets the raw text, not the formatted text.

Comment: @Jeff Mercado & Charles Mager I am not testing Microsoft's work. I am testing to make sure I did it right. Besides, half the point of unit testing is having some piece of mind in well written code. I want that piece of mind.

Comment: You should be testing that the _value_ that the object holds is what you expect it to be, not that it was encoded correctly. If it was not encoded correctly, that means you generated the wrong values in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it: Text elements in XML are nodes too.

```
var el2XML = myXDoc.Descendants("element2").First();
var porkAndAmpSemicolonBeans = el2XML.FirstNode.ToString();
```

You'll want to also check `el2XML.Nodes.Count` to make sure there's exactly one child in there.

---

`System.Xml.XmlDocument` is another option, because `XmlNode` has an `InnerXml` property that'll give you what you want:

```
var morePorkAndBeans = doc.SelectSingleNode("//element2").InnerXml;
```